# Blender doesn't use system resources optimally

Tags: animation, performance, optimization, system, frame-rate

let me just preface this by saying I am new to Blender and have a very minimal knowledge pf it as of now. 
The problem happened as I was following along with a tutorial and while doing a cloth simulation, I was getting about 0.4 fps (this was my first time running an animation), I checked blender's usage of system resources via task manager and everything was under utilised, with blender using memory 6-7%, cpu 8-12%, gpu 2-4% and no other major applications running. I have looked for ways to make it use more of these resources but couldn't find any that made much difference, I did in the end get it to 2 fps but that was due to a post that said scaling small objects up makes blender process the simulation better. I am hoping someone here can tell me how to optimize blender to better use these resources. I am running the animation in viewport and solid shading, this isn't with regards to rendering speeds although even then the system resources remain under-utilised.

My specs:

Dell XPS 15 9560 | Windows 10 v. 1909 64-bit

GPU - Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050

CPU - Intel Core I&-7700HQ @ 2.80Ghz (8-core)

RAM - 32 GB

Please let me know if the information is incomplete.

Comment: You did not mention anything about your GPU drivers. Are they up to date? Old drivers is by far the most common cause of problems in Blender.

Comment: Yeah they are up to date, the comments under stphnl329's answer contains a lot of troubleshooting, conclusion seems to be that the cpu is being capped by the system  at 28% causing issues, if you know any solutions please let me know.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue was inaccurate reporting of CPU usage by the Windows Task Manager.

Answer (score 4):

Blender most likely is fully using your system resources. In the task manager, change one of the charts to display *CUDA* and you'll see that its being fully utilized.

[image]

I just started a render on my computer, and you can clearly see when it fully using the GPU resources for CUDA even though it says usage is just 12% in total.

[image]

**Edit**

Windows may throttle your performance based on your power settings. Open up the start menu and search up *Edit Power Plan*.

[image]

Then go to *Change Advanced Power Settings*, and under *Processor Power Management*, check that the *Maximum Processor State* is set to 100%.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107528/discussion-on-answer-by-stphnl329-blender-doesnt-use-system-resources-optimally).